# selenium Python sort the list of web elements in Descending order

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, selenium-webdriver, automation

How to perform sorting function using mouse hover action in selenium (Python)

The below website is an example which contains list of elements which should be sorted out in "Descending " Order.
Eg website- https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: Could you elaborate it further ?

Comment: Hi pritham I appreciate your response please visit that website and there you can find the list of web elements which we have to sort the items in a descending order it should be in Python script! We can make it by move by offset method and some sorting functions in Python! This topic is nowhere available in Internet !

Comment: Are you trying to sort the elements if they are not in any order to be sorted in Descending order?

Comment: Yup exactly @NaveenChandar Let us know if u get any pinch of idea using "Python"!!